# Case insensitive jsonPath expression?

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am using Jayway JsonPath (https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath).

I am handling JSON data which contains HTTP request headers. Accordingly, the "name" elements are not in consistent letter case. For example:

```
"headers":{
    "Cookie":"token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9",
    "origin":"http://www.foobar.com"
}
```

versus

```
"headers":{
    "cookie":"token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9",
    "Origin":"http://www.foobar.com"
}
```

The `cookie` and `origin` header names vary in letter case, but the cookie values are going to be case sensitive.

I am trying to obtain header values using:

```
JsonPath.compile("$.headers.cookie");
JsonPath.compile("$.headers.origin");
```

But I am being stymied by the varying letter case used in the header names. I am not finding a way of specifying case insensitive path values. I can't just lowercase the json that will be searched as that will corrupt the cookie values. I suppose I could search for both all lower case and capitalized variants, but that feels klugie. Any suggestions?

Comment: For now, I am working around this issue by pre-processing the json string as follows:

    json = json.replaceAll("(?i)\"headers\"", "\"headers\"");
    json = json.replaceAll("(?i)\"cookie\"", "\"cookie\"");
    json = json.replaceAll("(?i)\"origin\"", "\"origin\"");

Comment: You can search for both. Or, you can parse the JSON into a POJO, tolerating case-insenstive field names. Both [Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13171058/880772) and [Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10079617/880772) can do that.

Comment: @Jaffadog Please never use simple text substitution/regexps to perform such transformations: it's totally unsafe and can easily cause data corruption, transforming not only top object property names.